# How can i fix 'case 1' in arduino

Tags: arduino

This is code

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
int rxPin=2; int txPin=3;
SoftwareSerial BTSerial(rxPin,txPin);
int ledPin[4]={6, 9, 10, 11};
int k, num;
byte phoneData;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
BTSerial.begin(9600);
for(k=0;k<4;k++){
pinMode(ledPin[k], OUTPUT);
}}

void loop(){
if(BTSerial.available()>0){
phoneData = BTSerial.read();
num=phoneData-1;
switch(phoneData){
  
case 1:
while(phoneData == 1){
int val1 = analogRead(A2);
int val2 = map(val1, 0, 1023, 0, 255);
analogWrite(6,val2);
analogWrite(9,val2);
analogWrite(10,val2);
analogWrite(11,val2);
Serial.println(val2);
delay(20);}
return;
break;

case 5:
if(phoneData == 5){
for(k=0; k<4; k++){
digitalWrite(ledPin[k], LOW);}}
break;

}}}
```

Case 1 is working but can't break and case 5 doesn't work

Why this does not work how can i fix?

I want to case 1 is turn on LED use phone and control brightness use Potentiometer and
case 5 just turn off LED

Comment: if you send "1" from serial Monitor, it is the character `1` which has ASCII code 49. you don't have `case '1':` or `case 49:`

Answer (score 0):

Your switch works on `phoneData` already, so it's pointless to check again inside the case.

The reason why your code doesn't work is that once you enter `case 1`, the while loop never ends. To fix your code, do the following:

1. Remove the `while (phoneData == 1) {` loop in `case 1:`.
2. Remove the redundant `return` in `case 1:`.
3. Remove the `if (phoneData == 5) {` condition in `case 5:`.

Comment: still doesn't work